# How to write symbols bold font in xmgrace?

Tags: xmgrace

Hi I can write symbols in xmgrace but couldn't find option to bold symbol (for example , I couldn't write bold mu symbol. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I wondered many times myself. Unfortunately, I think xmgrace does not make it possible, although you could produce eps files and then add bold symbols in post-production by using other software packages such as inkscape.

Comment: I am using inkspace but lots of problem in resizing figures. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @krishna I agree with this answer. You can also increase font size, though.